# Cambiar de página con InkWell - Flutter - Error

Tags: flutter

Buenas estoy intentando hacer un cambio de página con InkWell en flutter pero no lo consigo. No sé que puede estár mal, pongo el código a ver si alguien me puede echar una mano.
La idea es poner un CardView como en Android que muestre una imagen con un texto debajo, al hacer clic en este nos envíe a la segunda página pero no consigo que mediante InkWell redirija a la página segunda.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:juegos_memoria/second_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("BuildContext in MyApp: $context"); // Imprime el contexto de MyAp
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Página principal',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // TRY THIS: Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see
        // the application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app,
        // try changing the seedColor in the colorScheme below to Colors.green
        // and then invoke "hot reload" (save your changes or press the "hot
        // reload" button in a Flutter-supported IDE, or press "r" if you used
        // the command line to start the app).
        //
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // state is not lost during the reload. To reset the state, use hot
        // restart instead.
        //
        // This works for code too, not just values: Most code changes can be
        // tested with just a hot reload.
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.black),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(
            child: Text("Juegos"),
          ),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 250.0,
            child: SizedBox(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.replace(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
                  );
                },
                child: Card(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: IntrinsicHeight(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Image.asset(
                            'assets/imagen.png',
                            height: 40.0,
                            width: 40.0,
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                            child: const Text("Juego número 1"),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Esto sería del primer archivo, es decir, de la página principal.
Llevo poco tiempo con Flutter, únicamente 2 días y no tengo ni idea de que puede estar mal porque todavía estoy haciéndome a la sintaxis.
Desconozco los elementos que se pueden utilizar a la hora.
Pongo el código de la segunda página.

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:flutter/widgets.dart";

class MemoriaAuditiva extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Segunda Página'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Estás en la segunda página'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Me marca el siguiente Error pero no consigo entender porque no coge el parámetro context.
Error

```
Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a
descendant of a Navigator widget.
```

Si alguien puede echarme una mano se lo agradezco.

Answer (score 0):

El error:

> Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a
> Navigator. The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator
> must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.

El mensaje indica el problema, sucede al utilizar el Navigator con un contexto que no está asociado directamente con la estructura de navegación. En este caso te sugiero cambiar el uso de Navigator.replace por Navigator.push y usa el contexto de InkWell

```
...
child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
                  );
                },
...
```